# Exponents with the same power

Tags: calculus, analysis, logarithms, exponentiation

I've wanted to practice solving simple operations on exponents, so I've made a couple of equations to which I know the answers.

$$5^x -4^x = 9$$

I feel really stupid, because I can't solve this one (obviously the answer is 2). I can't separate the x's after using logarithms.

Any hints? Thanks.

Comment: Probably related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/61812/proving-that-2-is-the-only-real-solution-of-3x4x-5x

Comment: I don't think there is any general, elementary way to solve such equations, except numerically or by guessing the solution.

Comment: you can try take ln on both sides

Comment: @YilunZhang won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said by other participants, equations such as $$a^x+b^x=c$$ do not have explicit solutions in the general case. Only numerical methods (such as Newon) can be used and, in some cases, this can require a "good" starting point.  In the case you give, is is quite clear that starting on the left of the solution can lead to serious problems since the derivative is very small. Starting from the right would lead easily to convergence.

Being very lazy and starting iterating at $x=4$, Newton successive iterates are :$3.44701$, $2.92838$, $2.47921$, $2.16102$, $2.02198$, $2.00045$, $2.00000$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $f(x)=5^x-4^x$. Then $f'(x)=5^x\log 5-4^x\log 4$. Clearly, $f'(x)>0$, for all $x\ge 0$. Thus, for $x>2$ we have that $f(x)>9$, while for $x\in [0,2)$, we have that $f(x)<9$. Also, for $x<0$, $5^x<1$ and $4^x<1$, and thus $f(x)<9$. Thus the only solution is $x=2$.

Comment: Thanks for response! You clearly proved that the solution is x=2, but I was interested in a method of solving such equations (where it is not so easy to guess the correct solution).

Answer (score 0):

An equation like $$a^x-b^x=c$$ usually doesn't have closed-form solutions.

Anyway, using the substitution $t^n=b^x$, it becomes

$$t^{n\ln a/\ln b}-t^n=t^m-t^n=c.$$

For $n,m\in\{1,2,3,4\}$, you get a polynomial and analytical solutions are possible, though sometimes quite complicated.

For instance,

$$8^x-4^x=9$$yields by the Cardano formula
$$t^3-t^2=9,$$
$$t=\sqrt[3]{\frac{\sqrt{741}}6+\frac{245}{54}}+\sqrt[3]{-\frac{\sqrt{741}}6+\frac{245}{54}}+\frac13$$
and
$$x=\log_2(t).$$