# solve $3^x +4^x = 5^x$ in $\Bbb R$

Tags: calculus

solve the following equation :

$$3^x +4^x = 5^x \text{ in } \Bbb R$$

the trivial answer is $x=2$ .

Comment: sooo... i guess you solved the equation?

Comment: Interestingly, [$2$ is the only real solution to this equation](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/61812/proving-that-2-is-the-only-real-solution-of-3x4x-5x)

Comment: @5xum. no i can not yet

Comment: فرانك جواب خوبي داده در پايين. واقعا عالي حل كرده. پيكير همين روش باش

Comment: @amirbahadory But you did. You found a solution, right?

Comment: @5xum.yes i find x=2

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let $f(x)=\frac{3^x+4^x}{5^x}=(\frac{3}{5})^x+(\frac{4}{5})^x$, not hard to see $f$ is continuous and monotonically decreasing so $f(x)=1$ only has unique solution $x=2$.

Answer (score 2):

$$\left( \frac{3}{5} \right)^x+\left( \frac{4}{5} \right)^x=1$$
Then $x=2$

$f(x)=\left( \frac{3}{5} \right)^x+\left( \frac{4}{5} \right)^x$decreasing function