# how to generally approach these types of problems? $4^{x-1} + 4^{2-x} = 5 $

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponential-function

$4^{x-1} + 4^{2-x} = 5 $

I know the result easily but I lack the general reasoning behind it?
Should I use $ln$ or other approaches?

Comment: How do you know the result easily? Is it in positive integers? Or all real numbers? Anyway, see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/61812/proving-that-2-is-the-only-real-solution-of-3x4x-5x/61819) how to approach such questions.

Comment: Let $z=4^x$.  Then your equation reads $\frac z4+\frac 8z=5$.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I forgot to write the solution is in real numbers only. And yes, in this case I see that it should be 4+1 = 5 and I am just trying to find for which x the x-1 = 0 and 2-x = 1 or x-1 = 1 and 2-x = 0.

Answer (score 3):

You have to turn it into an algebraic equation. This is suggested by $4^x$ and $4^{-x}$. Namely, if you call $4^x=t$ then you obtain an equation of the type $at^2+bt+c=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Substitute $u=4^{x-1}$ so that ${1\over u}=4^{1-x}$.  Then the equation becomes $$u+{4\over u}=5$$ or $$u^2-5u+4=0$$